# Query a Product's SKU's by metadata field?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

Is there a query I can do to retrieve all the SKUs for a Product in Stripe?

Also, I'd like to query that set for the one that has a specific value of a metadata field.

Is this possible?

> #### Context
>
> I'm handling voucher codes (my own app does these, not stripe; stripes 'coupons' are for subscriptions only, what I'm doing here are one off payments) for the same product as different SKUs of the same product, but each with a unique price, and I put `voucher_code` in the SKU metadata (perhaps it could go in description, but I haven't optimised to that point yet).
>
> I've set `voucher_code` in `metadata` on each of five sku's on a
>   product, each corresponding to a different voucher, and would like, from my client js, to find the sku with a given `voucher_code`.
>
> This is so I can put the correct sku on a pay button with
>   `.redirectToCheckout()` that points to the approriate sku for the
>   voucher code my app already knows that the user has entered (vouchers
>   handled on my app, not on stripe, however, to make this work i've
>   added the code as metadata to the sku, as noted).

I'm currently using Stripe PHP if that's of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I drafted this question but then found the solution myself, but since it might be of use to others, I thought I'd post the solution.

Using stripe php in laravel I got some very elegant code for this
(you could do the same thing on the client in javascript of course, I just chose to do it on the server here).

```php
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(config('services.stripe.secret'));

$sku = collect(\Stripe\SKU::all()->data)->first(function($sku) use ($code) {
    return $sku->metadata['voucher_code'] === $code;
});
```

Then my php controller passes the `$sku` to the view which does `$sku->id` to put the right SKU on the pay button, job done.